# Kubernetes Operator CSV stuck pending

Tags: kubernetes, operator-sdk

I'm trying to install a Kubernetes operator into an OpenShift cluster using OLM 0.12.0. I ran `oc create -f my-csv.yaml` to install it. It is created successfully, but I do not get any results.

In the olm operator logs I find this message:

```
level=info msg="couldn't ensure RBAC in target namespaces" csv=my-operator.v0.0.5 error="no owned roles found" id=d1h5n namespace=playground phase=Pending
```

I also note that there is no InstallPlan created to make the accounts that I thought it was making.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This message probably means that the RBAC assigned to your service account does not match the requirements specified by CSV (cluster service version).

In other words, while creating an operator you define CSV which defines the requirements for creating your custom resource. Then, when operator creates the resource it checks if the used service account fulfills these requirements.

You can check the [Hazelcast Operator](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-operator) we created. It has some requirements regarding RBAC. So, before installing it, you need to apply the following [RBAC file](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-operator/blob/master/hazelcast-rbac.yaml).

Comment: So I am a full system admin and I created the CSV and I'm assuming it runs under either my permissions or those of OLM which has successfully created other operators, but not in this namespace. It seems OLM and I are credentialed properly.

What I believe I've seen is the CSV creating the accounts needed to services the operator. My CSV specifies the permissions and name of the service-account to create and run the container that does the operations. Are you suggesting that should be a manual process?

Comment: Depending on the operator it may use some specific service account name. Then, you may need to create it manually.